# is their A list of safe file ext that I can delete off my computer

Tags: batch-file

I just got my son A used computer but their are over 28,000 files on it I would like to know if their is A list of file ext that I can delete safely.please help I have looked at other sites but they just give me the ones I already know about like *.log,*.tmp is their any more

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall a new and clean operating system?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not 100% sure of the computer's history (and even if you are) I would **strongly** suggest formatting the disk and reinstalling Windows from scratch.  A second-hand computer could have all sorts of malware you don't know about.  And if there are any root-kits on-board you're not going to see them in file listings anyway.

Even without malware a cleanly installed system will generally run much better than one that's just had a bunch of crud removed.